# How to detect `getRedirectResult()` state after `signInWithRedirect()`

Tags: firebase-authentication

I'm using  `signInWithRedirect(provider)`, and `getRedirectResult()` to fetch the result after sign-in from provider (i.e. Google).

The problem I am facing is that, it seems `getRedirectResult()` took a long time (could take 3-5 sec) to resolve after redirection, and as a result, it's still showing the default view (i.e. sign-in form) after Google redirect, while waiting for the promise to resolve, which is not a great experience.

Is there a way to detect if the user is redirected from Google Sign-in, so that I can load up a spinner, while waiting for `getRedirectResult()` to resolve?

I have tried `document.referrer` with no luck.

Comment: May be I should re-phrase the question to **"How to show a spinner while waiting for `getRedirectResult()` to resolve after `signInWithRedirect()`"**.

Comment: I can confirm this is a problem without a decent built-in solution that I can find. Ideally  'state' would be an allowed parameter on auth providers (it's currently ignored see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider#setCustomParameters). You could get around this by implementing a manual oauth flow, but the most straightforward solution seems to be a custom `sessionStorage` setup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getRedirectResult()` should resolve quickly (fraction of a second) when there is no pending redirect. If there is a pending redirect, you should show some spinner before it resolves. BTW, you can also use `onAuthStateChanged` to detect the sign in state too regardless there is a pending redirect or not.

Here is a simple example of how to show a spinner. while the redirect operation is being processed.

```
// On load, show spinner.
showSpinner();
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
  // If user just signed in or already signed in, hide spinner.
  if (result.user || firebase.auth().currentUser) {
    hideSpinner();
  } else {
    hideSpinner();
    showSignInForm();
  }
});
```

You can also track it yourself.

```
// Before starting sign in with redirect.
window.sessionStorage.setItem('pending', 1);
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(authProvider)...

// On return.
if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('pending')) {
  window.sessionStorage.removeItem('pending');
  showSpinner();
  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(result => {
    hideSpinner();
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by no pending redirect? As far as I know, `getRedirectResult()` should be the first entry point after it get redirected from Google. The fact that I am seeing the default view after the redirect from Google, means that my page has been loaded, while waiting for `getRedirectResult()` to get resolved. Also, I am not using `onAuthStateChanged` because it's a complete redirect/reload of the page, which I think it's more suitable for using with `signInWithPopup(provider)`.

Comment: A pending redirect means that you are coming back from a `signInWithRedirect` attempt. You could be visiting this page for the first time (before sign in is triggered) and you could be visiting that page after you are already signed in. There are multiple scenarios. You seem to be only focusing on one.

Comment: I am actually focusing on the scenarios where user has not signed in, and signing in using `signInWithRedirect(provider)`. If the user has signed in, I won't have ask the user to sign-in again. Thks!

Comment: I added a couple of examples. You really have a lot of options and different ways to do this.

Comment: I prefer the 1st example as a solution as it doesn't involve "another" dependency on `window.sessionStorage`. Basically, you have to assume the view is initially "loading", and exit the "loading" state after `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` has resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that the always loading solution works for you, but should probably consider that you will be effecting 100% of your users for the sake of a much smaller number of use-cases

Comment: @som For my use case, my view is only doing a single thing, which is to sign-in / sign-out user, as such, it doesn't affect any other functionality for other users. Thanks for pointing that out.